# UK Tier 2 visa interview/biometrics and decision time

Tags: united-kingdom, colombia

I am applying for a Tier 2 general visa and I have all my documents ready, except my English language certification, which won't be ready until August 31, but my start date is September 17.
I was wondering if I can submit my application now (stating that I will submit my English certificate physically at my interview instead of it digitally with the form) and book my appointment after I've gotten my results in hopes of expediting the process to have my visa on time.

I would also like to know if applying now and choosing a later interview date would in fact get me a faster response or if the response time is always counted from the day of the interview. A detail I think is important for this question is that in my case the only documents I would need to submit at my interview would be my passport and the English language certificate.

I ask this because I've been looking for any information on what window of dates you get when you book your appointment, but haven't found anything helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted UKVI directly to answer my question. They said "[I]t would not be possible to submit submit supporting documents at a later time, and so it is advised all required items are ready to review upon attending your appointment", meaning that there is no issue if you apply before you have the documents, as long as you present them at the appointment.

They also told me that the application won't be processed until after the biometrics appointment, and that the only way to expedite the application is through the "premium services" that they offer at Visa centres.

Hopefully someone else having the same questions I had will find this useful.